# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Homepage_generalsettings

Tags: python, django

I am setting up git project to my local server.

when I try to makemigrations, migrate, run.

i get the following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Homepage_generalsettings

i have installed sqlite as well. I am using django version 3.

please help me to solve this problem[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9oit.png)

Comment: Can you please add your `models.py`?

Comment: https://github.com/raselcse07/Online-Newsportal-with-Django here is the source code from where i m cloning.

Comment: What happened when you ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: I m facing same problem django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Homepage_generalsettings

Comment: Your line 76 in LatestEntriesFeed is executing before making migrations and it's accessing a table that does not currently exist (you're trying to create it!)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the screenshot, you have code that's accessing the database outside of a view, during import time:

```
general_settings = GeneralSettings.objects.all()[0]
```

That's disallowed; that table doesn't necessarily exist while things are being imported.

You need to refactor things so this doesn't happen; one easy option is to make `general_settings` there a property:

```
@property
def general_settings(self):
     return GeneralSettings.objects.get()  # assumes only one `GeneralSettings` row
```

Comment: The problem is the related tables are not created in the db by migrations.

Comment: They can't be created by migrations because migrations can't run because of a crashing DB access when Django is importing apps during `makemigrations` or `migrate`.